# Bounding the L2 norm of a bounded function on a finite interval

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Consider a scalar-valued function $f(x)$ defined over a finite interval $x\in[a,b]$.  Assume that we know that $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for almost every $x \in [a,b]$, where $\epsilon$ is an finite positive scalar.  From this, we can infer that $f(x) \in L^\infty([a,b])$ since $\|f(x)\|_\infty<\epsilon$.

Is it valid for me to claim that $\int_{a}^b |f(x)|^2 dx < \int_{a}^b \left|\|f(x)\|_\infty\right|^2 dx < \int_{a}^b \epsilon^2 dx = (b-a) \epsilon^2$, which seems to imply that generally $\|f(x)\|_2< \sqrt{b-a}\|f(x)\|_\infty$ for functions defined on the interval $[a,b]$?

I know that the $L^p([a,b])$ spaces are supposed to be nested, with $f(x) \in L^\infty([a,b]) \implies f(x) \in L^2([a,b])$, which leads me to believe that I should be able to bound the $L^2$ norm using the $L^\infty$ norm.  But I'm getting confused because I don't know measure theory very well and because of the fact that functions in $L^2([a,b])$ are actually equivalence classes, and I'm second guessing  whether all of the steps I've written are mathematically valid.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have done is fine. The only thing I should point out is you don't have strict inequality; you get equality when $f$ is a constant.